# Change html code depending on the size of the array in php

Tags: php, arrays, url, tabs

Hi i have an array with some Urls and Html code for open this webs in others tabs. 
But the array dynamically changes the amount of Urls it contains. How can I change the Html code depending on the number of Urls that my array contains?

Code:

```
<?php
//$myarray can change dinamicaly the amount of urls contains
$myarray=array('www.google.com','www.piza.com','www.5.com');
?>
```

Now in my HTML code I have the code for open a tab, but i need open the array numbers of urls. In this case I need `window.open('')` three times.

```
<p><a href='#'
onclick='window.open('');
>Click to open webs</a></p>
```

Comment: To clarify, you want the single `<a>` link to open all 3 windows with one click? Or do you want 3 links?

Comment: Yes, i want a single <a> to open 3 windows in one time. In this example I write 3 Urls, but the array can change and contains more than 3. So I need create <a> to open x numbers of windows with one click depending the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//$myarray can change dinamicaly the amount of urls contains
$myarray=array('www.google.com','www.piza.com','www.5.com');

$windowsOpen = '';
foreach ($myarray as $value) {
    $windowsOpen .= "window.open('$value', '_blank');";
}
?> 

//now in my HTML code I have the code for open a tab, but i need open the array numbers of urls. In this case I need 'window.open('')' three times.
<p><a href='#' onclick="<?= $windowsOpen; ?>">Click to open webs</a></p>
```

Few things you should know, the URLs need to start with 'http://' or 'https://' in order to be an external link, if not it be considered as an internal link.
Moreover, most of the browsers will block the window.open if it is more than one as spam.

Comment: Thanks you for your help, Its Works fine1. Yes i know urls need http, I forgot to write it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (although I'd advise against it without careful sanitzation if the urls are originating from inputs entered by users)

```
<?php
  $arr = array("https://www.google.com", "https://www.pizza.com");
?>

<script>
  function openWindows() {
    var urlsArray = <?php echo '["' . implode($arr, '","') . '"]'; ?>;

    for(i=0; i<urlsArray.length; i++) {
      window.open(urlsArray[i]);
    }
  }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="openWindows()">Open Windows</a>
```